# Assign the return string to a label in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

how to set the value of a label with a text box string value

```
public ActionResult getComment(string comBox)
{
    var commentBox = comBox;
    Convert.ToString("commentBox");
    Console.Write("commentBox");
    return PartialView("getComment");
 }
```

And on my Partial view a want to show this string on a label.

How to do this?

Basically a comment box, i want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to show the comment in your partial view's label

Partial View getComment.cshtml

```
 <label>@ViewBag.Comment</label>
```

Action

```
public ActionResult getComment(string comBox)
{
    var commentBox = comBox;
    ViewBag.Comment=commentBox;// or whatever string you want
    return PartialViewResult();
}
```

Comment: sir, can you provide more details. it is not working. the label field is not getting set.

Comment: @user43553, Please add your partial view code. Its difficult to tell without your view

Comment: <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" ;/>

<input type="text" id="comBox" name="MyComment"/>
<label>(string)@ViewBag.Comment</label>

this my action field:

public ActionResult getComment(string MyComment)
        {
            var commentBox = MyComment;
            ViewBag.Comment = commentBox;                  
            return PartialView("getComment");
        }

Comment: @user43553, Updated my answer to return `PartialViewResult` no need to specify the view name, when a action name is same. Make sure that you have the getComment.cshtml view in correct folder

Comment: Still not setting the label with text box value. I checked the getComment,cshtml path and it is correct. The page loads correctly, just that it does not set the (string) value on button click.

Comment: @user43553, please update your question with `View Code, View Folder Location, View File Name`